# Log GET parameters to text file?

Tags: php

How to log GET request parameters to text file? For example `write.php?info=LOG_THIS`. I want to append the ip address followed by ": LOG_THIS" on new line in text file. How to do that?

Comment: See $_GET and file_put_contents() on php.net

Comment: Sorry but I don't code php. I need that for my C# app, and I'm sure it is very easy but haven't been asked here and I just can't do it

Comment: You have tagged `php` to this question.

Comment: Yes, I need php script that I can't create on my own, that's what I mean

Comment: @Nigel so you want us to code *for* you

Comment: < 5 lines of code on a question I think might be usefull for others. Yes, if you want to view it that way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
file_put_contents("your_file.txt", $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]. 
":" . $_GET["info"], FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
```

Documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?php
 //get data from file
 $content=file_get_contents("info.txt");
 //add ip
 $content .=$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
 //add get
 $content .= $_GET["info"];

 //write to file
 file_put_contents("info.txt",$content);
 ?>
```

You can find more infos on http://php.net ...

Comment: I am not the downvoter. But, what about IP address? Also, you should have explained about the assumption you made.

Comment: @Bhavik Shah : this is not a codewriting service so i leave sth to do for the OP

Comment: Yes. I understand. But, your answer here is creating confusion because you have made assumption but didn't described it in answer. Moreover, you have missed IP address. Link to official documentation would also be nice.

Answer (score -1):

//**********************START generate Log File**************************

```
<?php
$content=$_GET["info"];
wh_log("Log generate".$content);
function wh_log($msg)
{

    $logfile = 'log_' . date('d-M-Y') . '.txt';

    file_put_contents($logfile, $msg . "\n", FILE_APPEND);
}
?>
```

//END generate LOG FILE